# Appending a new input textbox DOM to HTML body using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to append an input box at runtime with value as "&#0" using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), but the value gets displayed as �. The below code works fine in Internet Explorer.

```
$('body').html($('<input id="myInput" type="text" value="&#0;"/>'));
```

Comment: Probably because you can't display a NULL character.

Answer (score 3):

I think when you are using .html() the content is considered to be [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) encoded, so try

```js
$('body').html($('<input />', {
    id: "myInput",
    type: "text",
    value: "�"
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/haaath1b/) (it looks like the code snippet also does the same, so here goes the fiddle.)

Comment: I cannot use this because data is unknown to me and it comes in bulk from the server for a table td. This null character is one among the many data and for this display is not proper but It works fine in case of IE8.